# resizing an existing array using `realloc`

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, calloc

I defined an array and I tried to resize using `realloc()` but it is not working. My question is can I do that using `arr[]` or do I have to use `calloc()` or `malloc()` first to define the array and then use `realloc()`?

this is my working so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray (int *arr, int size) {

    printf("{");

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (i == size-1) {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("}\n");
}


int main () {


    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printArray(arr, size);

    ////////////////////////////////////////

    int newSize = size++;

    arr = realloc(arr, newSize*sizeof(int));

    printArray(arr, newSize);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `realloc` can only be used to resize things allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and similar functions. Also, if `realloc` increases the size of the allocated object, the extra portion from the old size to the new size will be filled with junk, so printing its contents will print junk.

Comment: You can only reallocate dynamic memory allocations made with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. You can't pass a pointer to a local object to `realloc`, and assigning to an array doesn't work.

Comment: altair00, an _array_ size cannot change once it is defined.  Code can re-allocate memory that was allocated before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it seems you mean

```
int newSize = ++size;
```

instead of

```
int newSize = size++;
```

as **Craig Estey** pointed in its comment.

This array

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

has automatic storage duration.

You may reallocate an array that has allocated storage duration that is an array that was allocated using functions malloc, calloc or realloc.

Pay attention to that if the array `arr` had allocated storage duration then after the call of realloc

```
int newSize = ++size; // not size++

arr = realloc(arr, newSize*sizeof(int));
```

the last element of the array has an indeterminate value because it was not initialized.

Comment: `int newSize = size++;` --> `int newSize = ++size;` or [better] `int newSize = size + 1;`?

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks. A goof remark. I was nit attentive.:)